# MySQL -- Trouble with Indexes

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a bit of an odd situation and I'm trying to understand it.

I have two tables, I'll list the necessary fields.

```
products [MyIsam -- due to full text search]  
   product_id [primary index]
```

Has roughly 1,000,000 rows in it.

```
website_products [InnoDB]  
    website_id [primary]  
    product_id [primary]
```

Has roughly 6,000,000 rows in it.

---

Now when I do queries...

```
SELECT
    COUNT(`product_id`)
FROM `products`
```

Returns in 0.109 seconds with the result "1030650"

```
SELECT
    COUNT(wp.`product_id`)
FROM `website_products` AS wp 
WHERE wp.`website_id` = 1133
```

Returns in 0.577 seconds with the result "104150"

```
SELECT
    COUNT(wp.`product_id`)
FROM `website_products` AS wp 
LEFT JOIN `products` AS p ON p.product_id = wp.product_id
WHERE wp.`website_id` = 1133
```

Returns in ***38.173 seconds*** with result "104150"

An EXPLAIN SELECT yields:

```
1   SIMPLE  wp  ref PRIMARY,website_id  PRIMARY 4   const   204392  Using index
1   SIMPLE  p   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   imaginer_system.wp.product_id   1   Using index
```

Why is it so much longer when I join the table? How can I reduce that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: MyIsam and InnoDB do not place nicely together.

This link helped:
[Joining InnoDB tables with MyISAM tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475283/joining-innodb-tables-with-myisam-tables)

I converted my `products` table to be InnoDB as the FullText capabilities are supposed to match MyIsam's, and the search time went from 38 seconds to 0.4

We were running 300 sites on a server that was maxing out a server with 6 CPUs and it dropped to using 1/2 a CPU.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(wp.`product_id`)
FROM `website_products` wp LEFT JOIN
     `products` p
      ON p.product_id = wp.product_id
WHERE wp.`website_id` = 1133;
```

The optimal indexes are:  `website_products(website_id, product_id)` and `products(product_id)`.

Comment: I wonder if the issue is having two different storage engines.

Comment: I'm wondering about that too, but I don't have an easy way to determine it

Comment: I'm thinking this might explain some of the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475283/joining-innodb-tables-with-myisam-tables

Comment: Something else must be going on.   Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables, need to check more info that the limited summary you gave.