# MySQL SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL with multiple JOINS

Tags: mysql, isolation-level

If i have multiple tables joined within the same query some are InnoDB others are MyISAM, can i still use the below, given that it only works on InnoDB

`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED`

this is explained in post [Any way to select without causing locking in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917640/any-way-to-select-without-causing-locking-in-mysql) and is what i want to do

The tables i want this (none locking) to apply to are all InnoDB, but some of the joined tables are MyISAM.

I cant find the answer anywhere, as the examples only refer to very basic queries.

I did not really want to have to alter all tables to InnoDB.

i do have the above working with no errors, but am unsure if it is actually "stopping the lock"

Any advice much appreciated

Comment: Did you read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475283/joining-innodb-tables-with-myisam-tables?  Summarized:  Don't do it: due to a bug https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=57118

Comment: You're querying non-transactional tables, reading uncommitted changes, and now you want to query without locking. Your usage pattern suggests you don't really want to use a database, you want to use a **file**.